# ActiveMQ failover connection not working but works with single IP

Tags: java, activemq-classic, failover

I'm new to Java and writing a microservice that connects to an ActiveMQ cluster. I can connect to the cluster and read messages successfully when I use one single broker IP address. However, the connection doesn't work when I pass all IP's as a failover config.

Working config:

```java
    private static String url = "tcp://1.2.3.4:61616";
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
    connectionFactory.setUserName("abc@abc");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("abc");
    connectionFactory.setClientID("testingClient");
```

Failed config:

```java
    private static String url = "failover://(tcp://1.2.2.4:61616,tcp://17.3.2.50:61616,tcp://14.3.8.6:61616,tcp://2.3.0.4:61616,tcp://7.2.2.5:61616,tcp://32.33.1.6:61616)?randomize=false";
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
    connectionFactory.setUserName("abc@abc");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("abc");
    connectionFactory.setClientID("testingClient");
```

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have an extra `//` in the failover URL. Try using this instead:

```java
private static String url = "failover:(tcp://1.2.2.4:61616,tcp://17.3.2.50:61616,tcp://14.3.8.6:61616,tcp://2.3.0.4:61616,tcp://7.2.2.5:61616,tcp://32.33.1.6:61616)?randomize=false";
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, tried without // but still the same. I do not get any error message but no messages are read.  I'm running two microservices in parallel, one with single IP in broker URL and one with the failover URL. that's how I know when new messages arrive.